# Lazarus tchart label value onmousemove

Tags: delphi, lazarus, teechart

I'm drawing some TLineSeries on a TChart, I set values with this:

`serie.Add(IncMinute(now,-j),Random(100),'My Label',clBlue);`

And then I showing values on event ChartToolset1DataPointCrosshairTool1AfterMouseMove.

I get X and Y value with:

`y := Serie.GetYValue(tool.PointIndex);
my_date := Serie.GetXValue(tool.PointIndex);`

And now I need to recover the value of the label and I cannot find how to do this, I need to get 'My Label', but maybe I'm wrong and this is impossible.

Thank you.

Comment: `Serie.Source.Item[tool.PointIndex]^.Text`?

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you very much, it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Given you already have *tool.PointIndex* you can use that to retrieve labels, for example:

```
label := Serie.Labels[tool.PointIndex];
```

Comment: Thx but .. I'm not using teechart, I'm using TChart from Lazarus and it has no Serie.Labels.